# SwiftUI TabView PageTabViewStyle crashes without showing any error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, swiftui-tabview

I am trying to create an Image carousel using tabview and loading pictures    from firebase. Without showing any error message or code tabview crashing. Please shed some light on what's going wrong here.

```
struct HomeView : View{
var body : View{
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            ScrollView{
                CategoryView(homeViewModel: homeViewModel)
                PosterView(homeViewModel: homeViewModel)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarTitle("")
    }
}

}



struct PosterView : View {
@StateObject var homeViewModel : HomeViewModel = HomeViewModel()
@State var currentIndex: Int = 0
var timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common)

func next(){
    withAnimation{
        currentIndex = currentIndex < homeViewModel.posterList.count ? currentIndex + 
        1 : 0
    }
}


var body: some View{
    Divider()
    GeometryReader{ proxy in
    VStack{
        TabView(selection: $currentIndex){
            ForEach(homeViewModel.posterList){ item in
                let imgURL = homeViewModel.trendingImgDictionary[item.id ?? ""]
                AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: imgURL ?? ""))
            }
        }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .padding()
        .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            next()
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            print("Tapped")
        }
        
    }
    }
}
}
```

ViewModel: It contains two methods to fetch data and pictures from Firebase. That's working fine and am getting proper data. The only issue is while displaying it tabview crashes without showing any error messages.

```
class HomeViewModel : ObservableObject {

  @Published var posterList : [TrendingBanner] = []
  @Published var trendingImgDictionary : [String : String] = [:]

  init() {
    self.fetchTrendingList()
  }
   func fetchTrendingList()  {
    self.posterList.removeAll()
    firestore.collection(Constants.COL_TRENDING).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
        guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else{
            print("No Documents found")
            return
        }
        self.posterList = documents.compactMap({ (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> TrendingBanner? in
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as:TrendingBanner.self )
        })
        print("Trending list \(self.posterList.count)")
        print(self.posterList.first?.id)
        let _ = self.posterList.map{ item in
            self.LoadTrendingImageFromFirebase(id: item.id ?? "")
        }
    }
}


 func LoadTrendingImageFromFirebase(id : String) {

    let storageRef = storageRef.reference().child("trending/\(id)/\(id).png")
    storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }
        self.trendingImgDictionary[id] = url!.absoluteString
        print("Trending img \(self.trendingImgDictionary)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you open SwiftUI module sources, you'll see the comment on top of `TabView`:

> Tab views only support tab items of type `Text`, `Image`, or an image
> followed by text. Passing any other type of view results in a visible but
> empty tab item.

You're using `AnimatedImage` which is probably not intended to be supported by `TabView`.

**Update**
I made a library that liberates the SwiftUI `_PageView` which can be used to build a nice tab bar. Check my [story](https://medium.com/@eugenedudnyk/swiftui-scroll-like-in-uikit-using-only-swiftui-hidden-apis-8af2be0534c7) on that.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Any idea how we can display the image from the link using a carousel? Like it should be auto scrollable and each image should be clickable. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have working solution, but it’s worth of making it a library on GitHub.

Comment: That's great. Could you please guide me on achieving this?

Comment: This open-source library support any type of view as a tab item. https://github.com/xmartlabs/PagerTabStripView

Comment: Hey @Mac_Play please check the update on my answer - there is a really nice native way of building tabs now.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue recently on devices running iOS 14.5..<15. Adding `.id()` modifier to the `TabView` solved it.
Example:

```
TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
    ForEach(homeViewModel.posterList) { item in
        content(for: item)
    }
}
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
.id(homeViewModel.posterList.count)
```